# A div , but not the body, scroll to a specific element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a div "playlist" has a scrollbar , and there are several div of id "playlist_item" inside that div.

```
<div id="playlist" style="overflow-y:auto; height:100px;">
<div id="playlist_item_1"></div>
<div id="playlist_item_2"></div>
<div id="playlist_item_3"></div>
<div id="playlist_item_4"></div>
<div id="playlist_item_5"></div>
<div id="playlist_item_6"></div>
</div>
```

And there is a scrollTo function,

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#playlist_item_5').offset().top}, 1000);
```

but it works only on the whole body , how to change that to target on playlist? I have changed the selector to "#playlist" but it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to do something with margin. Dont think the scrollTop works on other elements.

Comment: I just tested your code with the selector changed to `#playlist`, it works for me. Have a look at [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tm904hL7/)

Comment: scrollTop works but i guess need to use `position()`

Comment: Works fine for me too **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kLm75q6q/)** with `#playlist` targeted

Comment: @AhsN Updated jsFiddle to work if element is not at top of body, using `position()` and set position relative for container: https://jsfiddle.net/tm904hL7/1/

Comment: Found that both offset().top or position() are work. The reason is the custom scrollbar plugin block the action: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with the selector #playlist.

```
$('#playlist').animate({scrollTop: $('#playlist_item_5').offset().top}, 1000)
```

Please look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohit181191/e146q6v3/)**

Comment: Thanks for editing..but it does not make any difference .It just looks good

Comment: That's not relevant in most cases where container element isn't at top of `body` or even regarding element margins. See fixed jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e146q6v3/1/

Comment: It is due to the plugin : http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ block the action. Thanks

Comment: According to the scenario mentioned offset and position does not make a difference.Yes it is more appropriate to use position() because it gives position relative to the parent which in this case is playlist container.[position vs offset reference](https://api.jquery.com/position/)